# Where is the Don't Starve save file located on Linux?

Tags: linux, dont-starve, google-chrome

I know that the save file is located in the Appdata folder for windows, where is it located in Ubuntu 12.04? I am using Google Chrome for both operating systems.

I wish to know this because I want to move my save from Windows to Ubuntu.

Comment: Can someone explain to me what Google Chrome has to do with Don't Starve?

Comment: @Mitja Because there is a Chrome App version of Don't Starve, and this version is what the OP's question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thank you to Avelarius on the Don't Starve forum for finding the location.

http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?10481-Where-is-the-Don-t-Starve-save-file-located-on-Linux

`/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1/File System/001/p/01` is the place in Windows.

`/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Default/File System/000/p/00` is the place in linux

I am still having troubles with actually getting the save to work though.

Answer (score 0):

~/.steam/steam/userdata/219740/ I believe.

This is taken from looking on forums and comparing to the windows version.

Comment: Ah, I mis-read as I thought you were using the steam version. As for the chrome version I'm not sure but possibly ~/.chrome/some/dir/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Steam, saves are located in

```
~/.steam/steam/userdata/{unique ID}/219740/
```

Otherwise (for example, if you purchased the game on GOG like me, or disabled Steam Cloud)

```
~/.klei/DoNotStarve/
```

The folder includes the Morgue, various savegames and your progress and characters unlocked.

Source: [Don't Starve Wiki](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Saving)